# Add a 0 or 1 based on a value in a certain column

Tags: python, append, iteration

I hope anyone can help me with the following. I have a list called: 'List'. And I have a list called X. 
Now I would like to check whether the value in the third column of each row in List is smaller than (<) X or equal/bigger than X. If the value is smaller I would like to add a 0 to the 6th column and a 1 if it is equal/bigger. And for each X I would like the answers to be added to the upfollowing columns to List. So in this case there are 4 X values. So as a result 4 columns should be added to List.  My code below probably shows I'm quite an amature and I hope you can help me out. Thank you in advance.

```
List = [(3,5,6,7,6),(3,5,3,2,6),(3,6,1,0,5)]
X= [1,4,5,6]


    for item in X:
        for number in row[3] for row in List:
            count = 0
            if number < item:
                List[5+count].append(0)
                count += 1
                return List
            else:
                List[5+count].append(1)
                count += 1              
                return List
       return List
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. The result is supposed to be `[[3,5,6,7,6,1,1,1,1],[3,5,3,2,6,1,0,0,0],[3,6,1,0,5,1,0,0,0]]`, is that correct?

Comment: Let's fix your problems one at a time. `for number in row[3] for row in List:` is not valid syntax. You need to nest another loop with a new level of indentation, similar to what you did with `for item in X:` and the 'loop' within.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed what I would like as an output. So each value in column 3 for each row in List is checked with all 4 values in X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List = [(3,5,6,7,6),(3,5,3,2,6),(3,6,1,0,5)]
X= [1,4,5,6]

scores = []
for item in List:
   scores.append(tuple(map(lambda x: 0 if item[2] < x else 1, X)))

result = []
for item, score in zip(List, scores):
    result.append(item + score)

print(result)
# [(3, 5, 6, 7, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1), (3, 5, 3, 2, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0), (3, 6, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should know that `tuples` (parenthesis enclosed lists) are immutable, so you can not change anything about them once they're defined. It's better to use a `list` in your case (enclosed by `[]`).

```
List = [[3,5,6,7,6],[3,5,3,2,6],[3,6,1,0,5]]
X= [1,4,5,6]

for item in X: # loop on elements of X
    for subList in List: # loop on 'rows' in List
        if subList[2] < item: # test if 3rd element is smaller than item in X
            subList.append(0); # push 0 to the end of the row
        else:
            subList.append(1); # push 1 to the end of the row
```

Comment: It is really not a good practice modifying a list or its contents while it is being used in an iteration.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your indentation is off (you should unindent everything starting with your `for` statement.
2. You can't `append` to `tuples` (your *rows* inside the `List` variable are actually `tuples`).
3. Since you are not in a function, `return` does not do anything.
4. Since indices start with 0, you should use `row[2]` for 3rd row.
5. There are more elements in your `X` than the number of rows in `List`.

That being said, you can also use list comprehensions to implement this. Here is a one-liner that does the same thing:

```
>>> List = [(3,5,6,7,6),(3,5,3,2,6),(3,6,1,0,5)]
>>> X = [1,4,5,6]
>>> print [tuple(list(t[0])+[0]) if t[0][2] < t[1] else tuple(list(t[0]) + [1]) for t in zip(List, X)]
```

will print

```
[(3, 5, 6, 7, 6, 1), (3, 5, 3, 2, 6, 0), (3, 6, 1, 0, 5, 0)]
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `[a + (int(a[2] >= b),) for a,b in zip(List, X)]` (and even the `int` is strictly cosmetic).

Answer (score 1):

```
List = [[3,5,6,7,6],[3,5,3,2,6],[3,6,1,0,5]]
X= [1,4,5,6]
elems = [row[3] for row in List]
for i in range(len(elems)):
    for x in X:
    if elems[i] < x:
        List[i].append(0)
    else:
        List[i].append(1)
print List
```

And you cannot use return if you are not using functions.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be doing what I want. Also thanks to all others, I really appreciate the tips and help.

Answer (score 0):

> agree with Selcuk
>
> [edited #1: Thanks @Rawing, I mistyped > as <]

Here is AlmostGr's version simplified:-

```
List = [[3, 5, 6, 7, 6], [3, 5, 3, 2, 6], [3, 6, 1, 0, 5]]
X = [1, 4, 5, 6]

for num in X:
    for item in List:
        if num > item[2]:
            item.append(0)
        else:
            item.append(1)
```

it runs for all elements in X and produces the output:

```
[[3, 5, 6, 7, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 5, 3, 2, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0], [3, 6, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you mrunmoy!

Comment: @AlmostGr: You said you expected `[[3,5,6,7,6,1,1,1,1],[3,5,3,2,6,1,0,0,0],[3,6,1,0,5,1,0,0,0]]` as output. Are you sure this code does what you want?

Comment: Sorry, @AlmostGr, I mistyped > as < in earlier code. Edited it now.

Comment: @ Rawing: You are right, I was a bit fast to judge I guess. The layout of the results look good, but the code does not make sence. So each value in column 3 for each row in List should be checked against all 4 values in X and added to the first empty collomn in  the corresponding row in List. So 4 columns are added to each row in List accounting for each X value.

Answer (score 0):

`return` needs to be called from inside a function. It exits the function and the value specified by `return` is given back to the function. 
So you can't use it in your program.

In the list, each row is actually known as a tuple. Tuples don't have the `append` function so you can't use that to add to the end of a row.

Also, you can't have two for loops in a single line. (Which is not a problem since we only need one to achieve your output)

I've modified your code so that it looks similar so it's easier for you to understand.

```
List = [(3,5,6,7,6),(3,5,3,2,6),(3,6,1,0,5)]
X= [1,4,5,6]

for item in X:
    n = 0
    for row in list:
        if row[3] < item:
            list[n] = list[n] + (0,)
        else:
            list[n] = list[n] + (1,)
        n = n+1

print List
```

You need to add with (0,) or (1,) to show that it's a tuple addition. (Or else python will think that you're adding a tuple with an integer)